# Sphinx field search operator not working from PHP's SphinxClient

Tags: php, sphinx

I can't seem to get the field search operator working from php.
A search like `@first Bob` works fine from the command line `search` tool, but when done from PHP it returns no results. (Just searching `Bob` from PHP also returns lots of results with a first name of Bob.)

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$sphinx = new SphinxClient();
$sphinx->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$sphinx->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$result = $sphinx->query("@first Bob");
```

It's been a few years since I've done much with Sphinx. Any idea what I've missed?

This is with Sphinx 2.0.8 and PHP 5.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, because you're not specifying an index to search it's trying to search some index(es) that doesn't have the field, and it's choking.

```
$result = $sphinx->query("@first Bob",'index1');
```

Use getLastError/getLastWarning to see error messages!

Comment: Only have one index set up, but specifying it explicitly seems to have fixed it.